# Mutate a prop in child component?

Tags: vuejs3

I have a component that receives an active state, so in the parent component:

```
<ChildComponent :active="active" />
```

Then in the `ChildComponent` this is received as a prop. Although, when `active` is updated in the `ParentComponent` I want to have the `ChildComponent` update, so I have had to declare it like this:

```
const props = defineProps(['active']);
const isActive = computed(() => props.active);
```

This works, when the `ParentComponent` changes `active` it is passed down to the `ChildComponent`.

But in the `ChildComponent` I need to mutate `active` too, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To allow the ChildComponent to both receive the active prop from the ParentComponent and update it when needed, you can use a combination of defineProps, defineEmits, and emit functions in the ChildComponent.

Here's how you can achieve it:

In the ParentComponent:

```
enter code here
```

```html
<template>
  <ChildComponent :active="active" @updateActive="updateActive" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      active: false, // Your initial value for active
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateActive(value) {
      this.active = value; // Update the active value from the ChildComponent
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In the ChildComponent:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Active: {{ isActive }}</p>
    <button @click="toggleActive">Toggle Active</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue';

export default {
  props: {
    active: Boolean, // Declare the active prop
  },
  setup(props) {
    const isActive = ref(props.active); // Create a local ref for active

    // Emit an event to update active in the ParentComponent
    const emitUpdateActive = (value) => {
      emit('updateActive', value);
    };

    // Function to toggle the active state and emit the update
    const toggleActive = () => {
      isActive.value = !isActive.value;
      emitUpdateActive(isActive.value);
    };

    // Expose the isActive and toggleActive function to the template
    return {
      isActive,
      toggleActive,
    };
  },
  emits: ['updateActive'], // Declare the custom event
};
</script>
```

With this setup, the ChildComponent receives the active prop from the ParentComponent and also has the ability to mutate it when the toggleActive function is called. The updateActive event is emitted from the ChildComponent to the ParentComponent, allowing the ParentComponent to update its active value accordingly.